# How to start a VNC viewer to display all previously saved VNC viewer desktops (that are now destroyed)?

Tags: vnc, restore, session, kde

Problem:

1. My current VNC viewer (let say VNC viewer 'A') resides on a machine (let say machine 'A') that need to be killed because our IT department need to rebuild the machine 'A'.
2. I have a lot of xterms, GVIM windows opened in this current VNC viewer 'A'.
3. We are advised to move all our works to a new machine.

Question:

1. I would like to ask is it possible to save all opened xterms and GVIMs in all the desktops from this VNC viewer 'A' ?
   Then I create a new VNC viewer that resides on another machine (let say machine 'B') and open all the previously saved/opened xterms and GVIMs that were in VNC viewer 'A'?

Currently the solution I am doing is:

1. In a new VNC viewer, I open all the previously opened xterms and GVIMs manually and it took me a long time.

I am using KDE Plasma 5 ...

Thank you.

Comment: What does the location of the VNC viewer have to do with the applications you are viewing through it? Can you not already connect to the same X session from another client, simultaneously?

Comment: @anx Could you explain how to connect to the same X session from another client? I know the session is already there but my current VNC viewer is destroyed. If I open a new VNC viewer I have to open new xterm and go to the path again to get the same GVIM I had opened previously , which is a waste of time.